# Is there a way to limit NSNotification?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, limit, nsnotification

I use `NSNotification` to send notification when switch is changed position to start updating annotations on map. My problem is that I have 8 switches and when user change position of few switches, map updates for many times. How a limit that to just one notification?

```
- (IBAction)saveSwitch:(id)sender
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyAppSettingsChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];


    NSUserDefaults *defs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs1 setBool: blackSwitch.on forKey: @"blackKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs2 setBool: greenSwitch.on forKey: @"greenKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs3 setBool: purpleSwitch.on forKey: @"purpleKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs4 setBool: orangeSwitch.on forKey: @"orangeKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs5 setBool: blueSwitch.on forKey: @"blueKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs6 setBool: redSwitch.on forKey: @"redKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs7 setBool: darkblueSwitch.on forKey: @"darkblueKey"];

    NSUserDefaults *defs8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs8 setBool: yellowSwitch.on forKey: @"yellowKey"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 

}
```

In another view

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppSettingsChanged:) name:@"MyAppSettingsChanged" object:nil];

}
```

Updating annotations

```
- (void) onAppSettingsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Settings was changed");

    //Create the thread 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must update some `BOOL`ean value to indicate that you are not currently processing an update, and proceed accordingly.  I.E.

```
- (void) onAppSettingsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Settings was changed");
    if (!myBoolToIndicateProcessing) {
      //Create the thread
      myBoolToIndicateProcessing = YES;
      [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

Then, when the reload has finished, set the BOOL back to NO.

Comment: Can you give me an example of updating BOOL value?

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'myBoolToIndicateProcessing'

Comment: Oh, just declare it as an iVar in the header file. `BOOL myBoolToIndicateProcessing;`

Comment: It works fine for once, but if user go back to settings and change more switches, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I added - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    myBoolToIndicateProcessing = NO;
    
} and it worked for me